# Magento 2: How to retrieve admin URI?

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, backend, admin-panel

I forgot to take note of the admin URI during installation.

Is there a way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get it from `app/etc/env.php` file,

**You have to get frontname from this file and suffix in your base url.**

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
```

Or

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Now your value is `http://127.0.0.1/magento2.1/admin`

Remove cache and check in your browser.

Comment: thanks , it works

Answer (score 35):

You can get the details by below command in you Magento 2 instance.

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

you can get the result like

```
Admin URI : /kqasuydi
```

Hope this is the simple and quick way to get.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer (Through file system):**

You can also retrieve the the Magento 2 Admin URL in `<your Magento install dir>/app/etc/env.php`. Example of the relevant file content:

```
'backend' =>
    array (
       'frontName' => 'admin_test',
    ),
```

**Quick answer (Using CLI):**

```
php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Where `newadminpath` is the new Magento 2 Admin URL

Answer (score 1):

You can get admin url from `app/etc/env.php`

Check **frontName** in `env.php`

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/etc from the root directory of your Magento 2 store. Here you can see env.php file and you can see the admin name:

```
<?php

return array (
 'backend' =>
 array (
   'frontName' => 'admin',
 )
```

You can also change the admin name by running the command in the root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="magento"
```

The above command will change the admin name as magento. You can access the admin panel by: www.domain.om/magento